# Using flume to dump data into S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flume

> org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found

I have added in core-site.xml.

```
 <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
    <description>The FileSystem for s3n: (Native S3) uris.</description>
</property>
```

bin/hadoop classpath
/opt/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*::/opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/hadoop//contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar

Hadoop version is 2.7.1 
Flume version is 1.6.0

Flume Agent config:

```
flume1.sources  =

flume1.channels = kafka-channel-allMsgs kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream

flume1.sinks    = s3-sink-user-match-served-stream s3-sink-allMsgs 

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.brokerList = 10.0.1.175:9092 , 10.0.1.229:9092

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.zookeeperConnect = 10.0.1.60:2181

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.topic = allMsgs

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.groupId = s3_flume_events

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.readSmallestOffset = false

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-allMsgs.parseAsFlumeEvent = false


flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.brokerList = 10.0.1.175:9092 , 10.0.1.229:9092

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.zookeeperConnect = 10.0.1.60:2181

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.topic = user_match_served_stream

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.groupId = s3_flume_matched_served_stream

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.readSmallestOffset = false

flume1.channels.kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream.parseAsFlumeEvent = false

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.channel = kafka-channel-user-match-served-stream

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.type = hdfs

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.filePrefix = user_match

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.path=s3n://<aws>:<aws>@bucket/served_message/%y-%m/%y-%m-%d

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.batchSize = 1024

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.rollCount=1270000

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.rollInterval=1800

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.rollSize=133169152

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.codeC=bzip2

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-user-match-served-stream.hdfs.fileType=SequenceFile

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.channel = kafka-channel-allMsgs

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.type = hdfs

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.filePrefix = allMsgs

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.path=s3n://<aws>:<aws>@bucket/all_Msgs/%y-%m/%y-%m-%d

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.batchSize = 1024

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.rollCount=1270000

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.rollInterval=1800

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.rollSize=133169152

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.codeC=bzip2

flume1.sinks.s3-sink-allMsgs.hdfs.fileType=SequenceFile
```

Comment: Have you added the lib which includes `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem` to the flume classpath?

Comment: Its in /opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/ which is hadoop classpath and also, while running flume agent, I tried adding classpath while running via appending -C /opt/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*

Comment: May you also post the agent description of your flume agent?

Comment: @ZeusNet Posted in Question

Comment: Mhh I'm not really sure but I guess that the problem is that the agent can't find  the FileSystem class. But I actually have no idea why.